# SQL in VBA query data where date is older than today

Tags: sql, vba, date

What is the way to filter data to dates older than today?

I am trying with the below code but get an error

> UNDEFINED FUNCTION GETDATE IN EXPRESSION

I have also tried with CURDATE() and this does not work either.

```
Sub CreateQueryTableWithParameters()
    Dim qryTable As QueryTable
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A:Z").Clear
        .Activate
    End With

' Define the connection string and destination range.
strConnection = "ODBC;DSN=RDBWC;UID=;PWD=;DBALIAS=RDBWC;"
Set rngDestination = Sheet1.Range("A1")
' Create a parameter query.
strSQL = "SELECT *"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM PDB2I.DI_NOS_OST_MVT_01 "
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE VAL_DT < GETDATE() "
' Create the QueryTable.
Set qryTable = Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(strConnection, rngDestination)

' Populate the QueryTable.
qryTable.CommandText = strSQL
qryTable.CommandType = xlCmdSql
qryTable.Refresh False
    With Columns("D:D")
        .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        .AutoFit
    End With        
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS Access (which seems likely with VBA), then `getdate()` is called `now()`.  So try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PDB2I.DI_NOS_OST_MVT_01 "
WHERE VAL_DT < NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying. I found that current date function in this is CURRENT DATE simply. Works fine